# QML TextField placeholderText disappear after push in StackView

Tags: qt, qml

```
//main.qml
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    StackView {
        id: stackView
        anchors.fill: parent
        initialItem: page1
    }

    Item {
        id: page1

        Column {
            height: parent.height * 0.2
            width: parent.width * 0.5
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            spacing: height * 0.04

            TextField {
                height: parent.height * 0.48
                width: parent.width
                placeholderText: qsTr("Placeholder 1")
            }

            Button {
                height: parent.height * 0.48
                width: parent.width
                text: qsTr("Next")
                onClicked: stackView.push(page2)
            }
        }
    }

    Item {
        id: page2

        Column {
            height: parent.height * 0.2
            width: parent.width * 0.5
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            spacing: height * 0.04

            TextField {
                height: parent.height * 0.48
                width: parent.width
                placeholderText: qsTr("Placeholder 2")
            }

            Button {
                height: parent.height * 0.48
                width: parent.width
                text: qsTr("Back")
                onClicked: stackView.pop()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hi everybody, I have a problem with the placehoderText property of TextField.
If i do the sequence -> "Next" on page1 -> "Back" on page2 -> "Next" on page1, then page2 is actually displayed but the placeholderText of the TextField is not visible anymore.
Is this a Qt bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Your code seems fine. I think it is a Qt bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StackView's goal is not that you tried to use ...
you should use SwipeView if you want prevent destroying items.

for your porpuse you can use a little customized SwipeView:

```qml
//main.qml
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    SwipeView {
        id: swipView
        anchors.fill: parent
        interactive: false;
        property int stackIndex: -1;
        function popIndex(){
            return (--stackIndex);
        }
        function pushIndex(){
            return (++stackIndex);
        }

        Component.onCompleted: {
            if(swipView.contentChildren.length>0)
            {
                swipView.stackIndex=0;
            }
        }

        Item {
            id: page1
            Column {
                height: parent.height * 0.2
                width: parent.width * 0.5
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                spacing: height * 0.04

                TextField {
                    height: parent.height * 0.48
                    width: parent.width
                    placeholderText: qsTr("Placeholder 1")
                }

                Button {
                    height: parent.height * 0.48
                    width: parent.width
                    text: qsTr("Next")
                    onClicked: swipView.currentIndex=swipView.pushIndex();
                }
            }
        }

        Item {
            id: page2

            Column {
                height: parent.height * 0.2
                width: parent.width * 0.5
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                spacing: height * 0.04

                TextField {
                    height: parent.height * 0.48
                    width: parent.width
                    placeholderText: qsTr("Placeholder 2")
                }

                Button {
                    height: parent.height * 0.48
                    width: parent.width
                    text: qsTr("Back")
                    onClicked: swipView.currentIndex=swipView.popIndex();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I only followed the documentation -> https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-stackview.html#push-method. It says "The item can be an Item, Component, or a url. Returns the item that became current." Anyway, thank you for your answer

Comment: @Fausto01 your right but when you use stackview ,that mean you wanna destroying item on pop ( like stack structure) , this solution didn't work to you ?if not, explain more that what do you want to do?

Comment: I need to use something like StackView to push and pop pages, but I need to keep memory of modifications when I go back and forward. If I use Component I need to declare various properties on the c++ side

Comment: So top code is that you want ! what's wrong with that? @Fausto01

Comment: Yes! I'm gonna try it and see

Comment: Hi @H.M. Thanks for your answer. I had a similar problem in which I wanted a mechanism like stackview and wanted the contents of views, like the content of text fields, to be persistent. Your answer solved my problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that by using Items that are parented to the Window like that, they don't get destroyed when they get popped. In the case of page2, that causes it to have a `null` parent and it resizes to 0x0. That then causes all of the other controls in that page to resize to 0 and that's a problem for the placeholder text (a situation they likely didn't expect).

If instead you use components, they will be sized correctly each time because they are created new at the right size and destroyed as needed.

```
//main.qml
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    StackView {
        id: stackView
        anchors.fill: parent
        initialItem: page1
    }

    Component {
        id: page1
        Item {
            Column {
                height: parent.height * 0.2
                width: parent.width * 0.5
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                spacing: height * 0.04

                TextField {
                    height: parent.height * 0.48
                    width: parent.width
                    placeholderText: qsTr("Placeholder 1")
                }

                Button {
                    height: parent.height * 0.48
                    width: parent.width
                    text: qsTr("Next")
                    onClicked: stackView.push(page2)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: page2
        Item {
            Column {
                height: parent.height * 0.2
                width: parent.width * 0.5
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                spacing: height * 0.04

                TextField {
                    height: parent.height * 0.48
                    width: parent.width
                    placeholderText: qsTr("Placeholder 2")
                }

                Button {
                    height: parent.height * 0.48
                    width: parent.width
                    text: qsTr("Back")
                    onClicked: stackView.pop()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a good solution but I've used static items because I need to keep memory of the modifications inside the pages. With this solution I need to declare various properties in the c++ side.